# Using CF-IPCountry Geolocation how to set redirect of website in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I using CF-IPCountry how can i set redirect of website based on the Geo location of user in C#

i can be able to identify the user Geo location

```
if(Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("CF-IPCountry"))
{
var userCountry = Request.Headers["CF-IPCountry"].ToLower();
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com");
}
```

redirected you too many times.